# Can't update data in bootstrap vue table

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Data is not updating in inline edit.when click 'done' data is being null.
I am using bootstrap vue table.api is working fine but inline edit is not working and it makes data as null in database.

Here is my bootstrap table code:

```
        <template #cell(name)="data">
      <div v-if="editting===data.item.id"><b-form-input type="text" v-model="form.name"></b-form-input>
</div>
      <span v-else>{{data.item.name}}</span>
    </template>

    <template #cell(price)="data">
      <div v-if="editting===data.item.id"><b-form-input type="text" v-model="form.price"></b-form-input>
</div>
      <span v-else>{{data.item.price}}</span>
    </template>

      <template v-slot:cell(actions)="data">
        <div v-if="editting===data.item.id">
            <button @click="updateTest(data.item.id)">Done</button>
            <button @click="editting = null">Cancel</button>
        </div>

        <div v-else>
        <a href="#" class="edit" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"  @click="editMode(data.item.id,data.item,data.item.index)"> <span ><i class="material-icons">&#xE254;</i></span></a>
        </div>
      </template>
```

script code:

```
<script>

export default {
data(){
    return{
    invoice_products: [{
        name: '',
        price: '',
    }],
    
  filter: "",
  perPage: 5,
  currentPage: 1,
  fields: ["id", "name", "price", "Actions"],
  columns:[],
  selectedRow: {},
  cancleButton: null,
  showDeleteModal: false,
  editting: null,
 form: {
      id: '',
      name: '',
      price: '',
    },
     form_index : 0,
    }
    }
},
computed: {
  rows() {
    return this.columns.length
  }
},
```

method of update:

```
           updateTest(id) {
         this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateTest/' + id,{

         })
            .then((res)=>{
                this.editting=null
                self.message = 'Data is entered';
                })    
    },
```

Controller.php update function:

```
    public function updateTest($id, Request $request)
{
    $updateTest = Test::find($id);
    $updateTest->update($request->all());

    return response()->json('successfully updated');
}
```

Comment: You haven't sent the data to be updated in the updateTest function?

Comment: I tried but it's not working ,   updateTest(id) {
             this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateTest/' + id,{
               name: this.invoice_products.name,
              price: this.invoice_products.price
             })
                .then((res)=>{
                    this.editting=null
                    self.message = 'Data is entered';
                    })    
        },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:
I had to pass the form in updateTest function.Here is my function:

```
        updateTest() {
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.form))
         this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/updateTest/' + this.form.id,this.form)
            .then((response)=>{
                this.editting=null
                this.getTests();
                alert("update");
                self.message = 'Data is entered';
                })   
    },
```